# How can i disable chrome "Use Suggested Password" on my type="number" Input?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

How can i disable chrome suggesting a random password on an type="number" input? i personally think it doesn't makes sense that chrome does that on an input with type="number", I'm using React and Next.js but I'm not sure if that's relevant

["Add suggested password"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRAyH.png)

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a number input & 1Password, mostly vanilla JS rails view.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the input `name` property solved the issue for me.

Comment: this is the answer. the `name` attribute communicates the expected behavior of the field to the browser. Clearly, Chrome cares alot more about the `name` attribute that the `type` ass it figures out how to handle the input field. `name` is more of a fundamental attribute than `autocomplete`, which is why it takes precedence.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

Chrome sometimes determines an input is a password field, regardless of the type.

Normally you would add `autocomplete="off"` on the input element. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#disabling_autocompletion).

However, there is currently a bug in chrome where this doesn't work. See bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466).

So there may not be a solution until they fix the bug. If your number field happens to be below another input that is a user/email field, maybe that is why it thinks it is a password field. If that is the case, you could try to put the number field in a different `<form>` tag.

Comment: that bug is really weird, I had a PrimeVue panel juste after in the DOM and settings its width seems to solve the problem.

Comment: This helped me for 1Password

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly enough, Chrome does not respect the `autocomplete="off"` property.

I believe Chrome matches autocomplete inputs by url path. And we had multiple inputs on the same route.

With MUI we added an `id=""` property on the non-autocomplete inputs.

Found the solution at [MUI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#autocomplete-autofill), but might also apply to normal html inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using type password, use type text and put a style `style="-webkit-text-security: disc;` and `autocomplete="new-password"`.

Comment: The question is about type="number".

Comment: It works for both number and text