# Why is Chrome Generating Password Suggestions in an Editable Dropdown with type='text' and autocomplete='off'?

Tags: html, google-chrome, primevue

I'm using an editable Dropdown element from PrimeVue, and I've noticed some unusual behavior in Chrome when I focus on the input field. It suggests a generated password, even though the type attribute is set to "text" and autocomplete is turned off. What might be causing this issue?

```
<input
    type="text" class="p-dropdown-label p-inputtext" tabindex="0"
    autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pv_id_13_list" data-pc-section="input"
    aria-autocomplete="list"
>
```

[image]

## Edit

My question is a duplicate of : [How can i disable chrome "Use Suggested Password" on my type="number" Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73180170/how-can-i-disable-chrome-use-suggested-password-on-my-type-number-input)